# How to fix withAuthenticator(App) Render Error

Tags: react-native

I installed @react-native-picker/picker and everything in my app was functioning correctly. When I implemented Auth and changed the export from `export default App` to `export default withAuthenticator(App);`
it broke and I have been receiving a Render Error saying that Picker has been removed from react. This happens regardless of if I import Picker or I delete Picker. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU2Dh.png)

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import Navigation from './src/navigation/index';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import awsconfig from './src/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <Navigation />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  pageContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  topNavigation: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    width: '100%',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Comment: Where is your picker import? Just wondering...

Comment: There isn't one in App.js which is the most confusing part. It is on my ProfileScreen.js folder. However it doesn't matter if I delete picker from the ProfileScreen.js, delete ProfileScreen.js, or uninstall the package I still get the same error.

Comment: strange, I have no idea then. Maybe another package or dependency you've installed also depends on picker and failed to download it. Reinstall packages? View list of installed packages?